# keystonejs behind nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, keystone

I got stack wiht keystonejs behind nginx .
the nginx .conf :

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /wanghuan/ {

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:3000/;

    }

    location ~ .*\.(img|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|js|css)$ {
        root   /Users/macmini/Desktop/test/wanghuan/public;
}
```

but keystone admin Ui still block ,the static file can't be find ,
how can i set the admin ui static file？

Answer (score 0):

You should just setup a proxy pass to pass all of your arguments to keystone like so:

```
upstream keystone {
  server localhost:3000
}
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://keystone;
    proxy_redirect off;

    }

    location ~ .*\.(img|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|js|css)$ {
        root   /Users/macmini/Desktop/test/wanghuan/public;
}
```

Not sure you are trying to put all of this under {domain}/wanghuan or just {domain} but this nginx config should work if you want the first option just change the location to be `/wanghuan`

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue. The assets for the sites front-end are being loaded via the proxy pass, however for the admin view, the assets (in /node_modules/keystone/admin) leep throwing 404, have spent a long nos of hours on this, still haven't solved it.

Comment: yes,It looks still not work :(,  did you have same problem?

Comment: I have a separate server with keystonejs of centos ，but need through  ngixn in a master server, Because   a number of projects unde the nginx，so the /wanghuan after {aomain} is necessary ， did you have same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn keystone.js init block with this additional option

```
'trust proxy' : true
```

and your nginx proxy code block just as simple as:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:3000/;

    }
}
```